# cakePHP: updating mysql table using WHERE clause with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to write this SQL statement in cakePHP syntax:

```
UPDATE students SET status = 'graduated' WHERE age = '23' AND major = 'math';
```

Now, the way I am trying to do this in cake is

```
$student->updateAll(  array('Student.status' => "'".$rowdata."'"), 
          array('Student.age' => $current_highest_age,'Student.major' =>
                    "'".$major."'"));
```

My variables: $rowdata = 'graduated';   $current_highest_age = 23; and $major = 'math'.

The table is not being updated. Is there a problem with my syntax? I will appreciate your help.

UPDATE ON THE QUESTION:

Actually, I found out where I was wrong in my syntax. The cake code should be `'Student.major' => $major` instead of `'Student.major'=>"'".$major."'"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You are double escaping

[updateAll](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions) expects the fields to be SQL expressions (or simply quoted strings) but the conditions should not be. As such, the query you're going to be generating right now is:

```
UPDATE 
    students
SET
    status = 'graduated' 
WHERE 
    age = '23' AND 
    major = '\'math\''
```

To prevent the extra quotes, which will cause the syntactically-valid statement to match 0 rows, just let Cake take care of your conditions for you as with other methods:

```
$student->updateAll(
    array('Student.status' => "'".$rowdata."'"), 
    array(
        'Student.age' => $current_highest_age,
        'Student.major' => $major
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to update a field of a Model

```
$this->Testing->updateAll(
    array('Testing.door_open_close' => $door_open_close),   // value that is updated                  
    array('Testing.id' => $zoneId)     // condition field of a Model
);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
UPDATE students ...
       ^^^^^^^^--- student WITH an S
```

v.s.

```
array('Student.age')
       ^^^^^^^  - student WITHOUT an S
```

Comment: -1 That's a [CakePHP convention](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions) - all queries are of the form `VERB ``table`` as ModelName ...`. All tables are plural, all model names are singular and all queries alias the table to the model name.

Comment: Actually, I found out where I was wrong in my syntax. The cake code should be `'Student.major' => $major`   instead of `'Student.major'=>"'".$major."'" `